# How to get attribute value on click?

Tags: angularjs

Hey guys I need to get tha data value of the button when I click on it. I tried  in this way but it doesn't work..

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myAppCtrl", function($scope, $attrs) {
    $scope.events = {}
    $scope.events.btnLoadMore = function() {
        var panel = $attrs.emptywidget;
        alert(panel);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
  <button data-emptywidget="#panel2" ng-click="events.btnLoadMore()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of angular.element and passing in the $event source as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ahchurch/9USEv/1/

```
<div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">
    <button data-emptywidget="#panel2" ng-click="events.btnLoadMore($event)">Click</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myAppCtrl", function($scope, $attrs) {
    $scope.events = {}
    $scope.events.btnLoadMore = function($event) {
        console.log($event);
        var panel = angular.element($event.target).attr("data-emptywidget");
        console.log(panel);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, this one is the better solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can access that data attribute would be through standard DOM access, which is not wise inside a controller. The `$attrs` variable you're passing into your controller also won't give you very much, as your controller doesn't directly related to anything (or at least it doesn't need to or shouldn't)

If you need to do something like that, then you could change your `ng-click` to something like

```
ng-click="events.btnLoadMore('#panel2')"
```

Then change the definition of your `btnLoadMore` function to take an argument. Alternatively you can write a directive that would be given that value, but that's more complex. But it depends what you want to do with it really. The above should work though

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few different things.

1) You can pass in the data via the function so like

```
ng-click="events.btnLoadMore('#panel2')"
```

Then change your function to match so:

```
$scope.events.btnLoadMore = function(panel) {
    alert(panel);
}
```

2) You can pass in the data via the $event parameter

```
ng-click="events.btnLoadMore($event)"
```

Then change your function to match so:

```
$scope.events.btnLoadMore = function(clickEvent) {
    alert(clickEvent.target.attributes['data-emptywidget'].value);
}
```

3) You can just look at the arguments passed in to the function

```
$scope.events.btnLoadMore = function() {
    alert(arguments[0].target.attributes['data-emptywidget'].value);
}
```